# Targeting multiple buttons and get different value by clicking different button

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to target multiple buttons and get different value by clicking different button.

Suppose there are 3 buttons: "button01", "button02, "button03".

This is my code:

```
var targetArr:Array = ["button01","button02","button03"];
for (var i:int = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++)
{
    var target = getChildByName(targetArr[i]);
    target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, targetFunc);
    function targetFunc(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(i);
    }
}
```

Instead of getting different value by clicking different button, I constantly get "3" as the value.
I want: clicking "button01" will get "0" as the value, clicking "button02" will get "1" as the value, and clicking "button03" will get "2" as the value. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! What is happening is that the reference to `i` is being shared by all of  your event handlers. What you want is a distinctive copy of the value of `i` when the event handler is registered.

To do this, you can create a new closure for each iteration of your loop.

```
var targetArr:Array = ["button01","button02","button03"];
for (var i:int = 0; i < targetArr.length; i++)
{
    var target = getChildByName(targetArr[i]);
    target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getTargetFunc(i));
    function getTargetFunc(value:Number):Function {
        return function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(value);
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening now is that we are passing the particular value of `i` to a helper function that then returns the event handler function. This way we are using a closure to *close* over the particular value of `i` at the time we register the handler.

**EDIT:** Here is another *slightly* different way of arranging things. For each iteration of your loop, you could call a function that registers the handler:

```
addHandler(i);
function addHandler(value:Number):void {
    target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, targetFunc);
    function targetFunc(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(value);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hey no problem! I've added another code sample to my answer that shows yet another way of tackling this problem -- ultimately using the same principle.

Comment: Thank you again for the alternative code. I think this one is easier for me to comprehend :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes I agree, the second approach is easier to read -- we don't have to deal with the confusion of returning anonymous functions. :)